# How to add attributes to Controller or customize a Controller in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I need to write a directive which sets scope in it like a controller. Inside it there are inputs and buttons. When some button click, it invokes $scope.refresh(), which passes the model value to some grids to make them refresh.

Most things work fine. I bind model to inside inputs, use ng-click to bind the button click event and it invokes the refresh() method. But in the refresh function, I need to get the ids of my data table and interact with it. For now I can only pass it through ng-click's method parameter. The code is below:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <input ng-model="year"/>
    ........
    <button ng-click="refresh('grid1, grid2')">Refresh</button>
    <button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
</div>
```

I think it looks ugly. If the grid ids need reuse in other methods, I have to pass it many times, but I don't know how to pass attr to controller or extend the Controller. Is there a good way to achieve something like this?

```
<div my-controller="MyController" grids='grid1, grid2' charts='chart1,chart2' ...>
    <input ng-model="year"/>
    ......
    <button ng-click="refresh()">Refresh</button>
    <button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Or maybe the idea is bad. Should I better use another way to do this job?

Updated:

The use case is like this:

I need to create a reusable component which contains some inputs (via transclusion I guess) as queries. The component is bound with some outside grids and charts (unfortunately they are not directive yet). There are buttons in the component which triggers refreshGrids or refreshCharts actions using ng-click. It needs the grid and chart ids to invoke their setQuery() method inside the action and pass the model (inputs' values) to the method. That's why I need to pass the ids into the component or the action.

The reason I use ng-controller is to create a new scope for isolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.

After digging into Angular UI's source code, I found the datepicker use a way to enclose a controller and link directive to it.

Check this line of code: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker.js#L135

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach is fine, but if you wanted to refactor your grids into their own directives, you would have access to the DOM element through the 'element' variable in the [link function](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

If you needed to do something based on the ng-click directive, you can watch a scope variable in the directive or listen to a broadcast on the root scope and take an action in the directive itself. Something like this:

```
<div id="dataGrid1" my-app-directive="fireACtion" ng-click="fireAction = !fireAction" />
```

Then in your directive just watch attrs.myAppDirective (which is fireAction)

```
scope.$watch(attrs.myAppDirective , function (newVal, oldVal) {
     //When the value changes, this will run
}
```

This will encapsulate all this logic inside the directive and you will also inherit the controller scope.

Comment: Good way to go. But since there are many actions/ng-click in the controller, I need to put them into the Controller attributes, like my second code snippet shows. I put "my-controller" along side with ng-controller in the same div element, as your way, the inner doms are gone. Is it related to the "transclude" attribute?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your use case, but if you put the directive on the actual grids themselves, each one will act independently. So if you have 10 grids and you wanted to have 5 actions on those grids, you just need one directive that contains 5 watches - one for each action. You have removed all this plumbing from the controller and put it in a reusable directive.